# Form with garbage Play Framework

Tags: html, forms, playframework

I am having an issue with my Play Form.

After submitting my form and reopening the same page, I am getting the previous submitted values.

What can I do to get a clean form?,

The submit process is working fine, besides this little issue.

```
 div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
    <h1 class="page-header">New Product  Form</h1> 
    <div class="row placeholders div-table">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 div-table-row">
            @helper.form(routes.Products.createProduct){
                <div class="form-group">
                @helper.inputText(form("name"), '_label->"Product Name", 'id->"productName", 'name->"productName", 'class ->"form-control", 'placeholder ->"Enter Product Name") <!-- End Product Name Form-->
                </div><!--End First Form Group-->
                <div class="form-group">
                @helper.select(form("type"),options(models.Type.values().toList.map(_.toString)), '_label->"Type", 'id->"type", 'name->"type", 'class->"btn btn-default dropdown-toggle")
               </div><!--End Second Form Group-->

                <button class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                }
            </div> <!--End Middle Content DIV  -->
    </div> <!-- End Middle content with SideBar-->
</div> <!--End Container -->
```

Comment: Would you mind posting your controller which displays and handles the given form?

Comment: Right the first sign should be a `<`, is this a error in your code or did you not copy&paste it in here? Also Daniel is right, we need the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix the issue. The problem was that I was initializing the form as static in my controller. Thanks to all for your help.